# Sorting a datatable affects reference datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a method somewhat similar to the one written bellow(this is just a pseudo-code I am working in C#):

```
function GenerateChart(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable dtChartTable = dt;
    dtChartTable.DefaultView.Sort = "SomeColumnName";
    //remaining functionality
}
```

what this above code does is it also sorts the records in dt. I am not getting why it is doing so. Just as a note: this function is called from two different places. at one place I am sending a Datatable object and at the other the Datatable is directly refered from the one stored in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. 
You are setting the dtChartTable variable to the same memory represented by the dt variable.
So, sorting the dtChartTable affects the same DefaultView property used by the second .

If you don't want this behavior you could create a copy of dt using

```
DataTable dtChartTable = dt.Copy();
```

but this is costly because in this way every datarow is duplicated.
Another possibility is creating a new DataView

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
view.Sort = "SomeColumnName";  
......
```

this doesn't affect the original dt.DefaultView and you can process your datarowview from this new DataView

Comment: yes since Datatable is of reference type so it does so. Can I do dt.Clone() and then import rows into dtChartTable is it as costly as dt.Copy()

Comment: DataView is the best option IMO.

Comment: If you are only interested in sorting, then, there is no reason to go all that way. Just create a different DataView.

Comment: yup I need to do some select operations too, but thats fine I guess. I can do those on DataView too. Thanks buddies!

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
DataTable dtChartTable = dt;
```

It make a new copy but both refer to same location in memory since Datatable is reference type and hence your changes in one reflects in other.

Instead do

```
 DataTable dtChartTable = dt.Copy();
```

This makes copy and refer to different location in memory. Changes in one do not reflect in other.